# connect 2 different .csv files in mysql with a composed key

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm a newbie in the programming stuff, and I need to create 2 tables in MySql. Tb1 will have ingredients, and the Tb2 will have dishes made with "pairs" of Tb1 ingredients. I will make 2 diferent files in Excel (.csv) and the doubt is how to connect the data from one to another. The idea is to have a composed key (with both id's of the Tb1 ingridients) in the Tb2. Is that possible, and how do I do it?

Thanks

I don't have code made. I know how to do the basic to load data to a table, the problem it's just the connection between both .csv files.

Comment: Only pairs of ingredients? What if you have a dish that needs more than 2 ingredients?

Comment: You should have 3 tables. A table of ingredients, a table of dishes, and a relationship table whose rows are `ingredient_id` and `dish_id`.

Comment: Please show sample data from the two `.csv` files.

Comment: What you're wanting is a many-to-many relationship which includes the use of a junction table. Basically create a third table with the columns `IngredientId` and `DishId` (or whatever the primary key columns are called), then set up a foreign key constraint to their respective tables. When you make a dish, create an entry in this third table for every ingredient and the associated dish.

Comment: You probably can't create the relationships by loading the CSV files. You'll need to write code that gets the IDs assigned to the dishes and ingredents when you load those files, and finds the matches to create the junction table.

Comment: Thanks guys. I had the ideia that I would have to do that third table, but I was hoping there was another way, that's ok.